# Swift : How to perform actions only if an array matches specific conditions?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

So I've encountered this problem (beginner in Swift, so you know) and couldn't find a solution here:

I have an array of buttons, that I associate to an `array` of `bools`, let's name it `litPad`.

Basically for instance if `button[i]` is highlighted, `litPad[i]` becomes `true` (by default I set the whol `bool` `array` to `false`).

What I want to achieve is perform certain actions only if some `bools` are `true` :

For instance if `litPad[3]`, `litPad[6]` & `litPad[12]` are `true` I'll perform an action, but these conditions have to be exclusive, meaning if those 3 buttons are highlighted but any other one as well the action won't perform, an other will (different actions for instance if only `litPad[3]` & `litPad[6]` are highlighted/`true` or if `litPad[3]`, `litPad[6]`, `litPad[12]` & `litPad[19]` are highlighted/`true`).

I can't seem to format correctly my if statements to match what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Make a list of the index numbers for which the condition is true. Now compare that list directly. If it’s `[3 ,6,12]` do that action, and so on.

Comment: Hi, please also include a code snippet with what you have so far, it'd make it easier for us to help! :)

Comment: thanks guys !
Yeah I wondered whether or not including a code snippet but I figured it was so basic that from my description it was not necesary ; Matt's answer solved my problem in the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a series of actions based on very specific patterns of "which ones are true", so just match against those patterns:

```
switch whichAreTrue {
    case [3,6,12]: doOneThing()
    case [3,6]: doAnotherThing()
    // ...
    default:break
}
```

I suppose the question then is: given an array of Bools, *how* do you know "which are true"? How do you derive the index numbers from the thing itself? Like this:

```
let arr = [true, false, true, false, false, true, false]
let whichAreTrue = arr.enumerated().filter{$0.1}.map{$0.0} // [0, 2, 5]
```

And now you have something you can match against.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
This is exactly what I was looking for and that perfectly worked, thanks :) 
I'm not used yet to switch statements, so much used to ifs from the other programming languages I've worked with before that I never think of using swtiches, glad I've encountered a problem needing them and showing me a good example of how useful they can be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Set` to keep track of which buttons are "on", and then build a `switch` statement for the individual actions:

```
var litPad = Set<Int>()

litPad = [ 1,2,5 ]

switch litPad {
case [1,2,5]: print("action 1")
case [1,2]: print("action 2")
default: ()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gereon !
This partially solves my problem which would be map out this set to the bool array, but the answer from Matt solved it.
But I'll dive more into Sets as they seem to be useful !